# Show that $7\mid 2^{3n} -1 \,\,\,\forall n\in \mathbb N^+$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, induction, divisibility

> Show that $7\mid 2^{3n} -1 \,\,\,\forall n\in \mathbb N^+$

Should I prove this by induction? If so, how should I go about it?

Comment: Complete the following statements:

1) Base case: if $n = 1$, then...
2) Assume for $k \in \mathbb{N}$ that $2^{3k}-1$ divides 7. What does this mean? How do you use this to show that it's true for $k+1$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't mind I'm gonna do some magic!

$$2^{3n}=(2^3)^n=8^n=(7+1)^n$$
Now use binomial expansion
 to get

$$\begin{align}
(7+1)^n&=\binom{n}{0}7^n+\binom{n}{1}7^{n-1}+\cdots+\binom{n}{n-1}7+\binom{n}{n}7^0\\
&=\binom{n}{0}7^n+\binom{n}{1}7^{n-1}+\cdots+\binom{n}{n-1}7+1\\
(7+1)^n&=7k+1\\
\end{align}$$

So We have
$$\begin{align}2^{3n}&=(7+1)^n\\
&=7k+1\\2^{3n}-1&=7k\end{align}$$

Hence

> $$7\vert2^{3n}-1$$

Comment: Holy moly, that is beautifully simple! Thank you!

Comment: I definitely will, I just need to wait a few more minutes until it lets me...but I definitely will, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** $2^{3n} - 1 = (2^3)^n - 1^n = (2^3-1)((2^3)^{n-1} + ... + 1)$

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively with some modulo arithmetic,

$$\begin{align}2^{3n} - 1 &= 8^n - 1\\
&\equiv 1^n - 1 \pmod 7\\
&= 0 \pmod 7 \end{align}$$